# the jnlp update process is corrupting the cache through hotspot network

Tags: java, caching, wifi, java-web-start, corruption

This post is about a problem from the Java cache. We have a jnlp file responsible of updating our app (so we cannot put it “offline”). The problem is that some of our users run the application behind a hotspot network through wireless. In this case, they have no access to Internet but the java webstart mechanism try to download the JNLP in despite of this. In this case, JWS downloads the HTML login page and put it in its cache without any check. In consequence, the next access through shortcut is impossible.

Is it a known issue and is there a workaround?

Thanks in advance for your replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI

We have removed the tag href from jnlp file and it's now ok. The jnlp is never updating but it's ok for us.